# AWS lambda with Amazon API Gateway accessing multiple bucket objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a created a React App for an existing simple BE implementation that stores all data in a JSON file, instead of a database. I was then asked to reimplement it, using AWS lambda, Amazon API gateway and storing the JSON file in a S3 bucket. Works fine, but I would like to have a side bar in my React APP, where I can access different JSON files. My question is, how is it possible to specify to my lambda function, which S3 object should it access each time?
Edit: Based on the comment, the API endpoints are used from an other service too, and cannot be altered, which is the root of my trouble.

Comment: You create object uri and send to lamda via api gateway as request payload. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

AWS has now made lambda functions called publicly by having AWS Lambda Function URL. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/
So, you can directly pass parameter of S3 object uri in lambda function from your app. You don't have to go via API gateway.